# Trigger function not updating ts_vector column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I want to select from multiple tables multiple columns, to update that into a ts_vector column. so that we finally can search over all the customer info.

Problem is that it looks like the NEW."Customer_id" / OLD."Customer_id" are not functional in the trigger function as it is now. if I execute the sql with some 'existing customer_id guid' it works fine.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.onadd_onchange_customer_function()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$

BEGIN


update public."Customers" set ("TextSearch") = 

(select to_tsvector(concat(a,' ', b,' ',c)) from

  (
     select concat("BarCode","FirstName" ,"MaidenName" ,"LastName" ,"SSN"  ) 
     from public."Customers"  
     where "Customer_id" = OLD."Customer_id"
  ) as a,
  (

      select string_agg(replace("CommunicationValue",' ',''), ' '::text) 
      from public."CustomerCommunications" 
      where "Active" = true  
     and "Customer_id" = OLD."Customer_id"
  )as b,
  (
      select string_agg(concat("AddressLine1",' ',"AddressLine2",' ',"AddressLine3",' ',"PostalCode",' ',"City"), ' '::text) 
      from public."CustomerAddresses" 
      where "Active" = true 
       and "Customer_id" = OLD."Customer_id
  ) as c
)
where "Customer_id" = OLD."Customer_id";


RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$;
```

::::::::::::ERROR running as a trigger::::::::::::

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "update public."Customers" set ("TextSearch") = 

(select to_tsvector(concat(a,' ', b,' ',c)) from

(
select concat("BarCode","FirstName" ,"MaidenName" ,"LastName" ,"SSN"  ) 
from public."Customers"  
where "Customer_id" = OLD."Customer_id"
) as a,
(
etcetcetctec...
```

Comment: So you have a trigger, that fires when `"Customers"` is updated and updates `"Customers"` again which again fires the trigger and so on and so on. At some point the stack is exhausted and you get the error message. Maybe you just want to set `new."TextSearch"` to something and return `new`.

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion.  The trigger updates the row, which fires the trigger, which updates the row, which fire the trigger, which....  If you want to modify the row being updated, you use a BEFORE trigger, and directly modify NEW.

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using? If you're on version 12+, a calculated column might be more straightforward than a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed a infinite loop.

Solution made the trigger run on all columns except the TextSearch column.

Thnx guys